# How can I detect univariate outliers multivariately?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, outliers

Chose hopefully a catchy title :-) I am looking for a simple algorithm to detect outliers caused by measurement errors

So assune I have given a multivariate sample (30 dimensions) and I want to detect outliers univariately, so I don't want to say that the whole 30-dimensional observation is an outlier but I want to say that e.g. for k=10 and t=161 there's an outlier where k is the dimension and t is the time..

However, I want to look at it multivariately. More precisely, I expect the values to correlate much

If let's say for t=161, only k=10 is extreme while for k=1,...,9,11,...,30 the values are normal, I'd expect k=10 to be an outlier caused by measurement error which I would like to eliminate.

However, if for t=161 many values k are extreme, I'd assume that they are probably correct and not mark it as an outlier

Also reversely, if for t=161 all values are extreme while only one value is normal, I also wouldn't want this observation to be marked as an incorrect outlier

I looked into mahalanobis distances but heard of two problems

1. It seems to not work very well with higher dimensions, 30 seems generally too much
2. It marks the whole 30-dimensional observation as an outlier which I do not want - I precisely want to extract single univariate dimensions from it

What would be a suitable algorithm?

Comment: welcome to the site. What are K and T?

Comment: I wrote that :-)